# Old OpenSSL problem

Tags: arch-linux, openssl, ssl

I am having a trouble with a program that needs old version of openssl.The program does not have support to upgrade it to new openssl version.

> Error creating SSL context (error:140A90C4:SSL
>   routines:func(169):reason(196))'

What should i do?

What information do you need? I can add them later

```
$pacman -Q | grep openssl
lib32-openssl-1.0 1.0.2.l-2
openssl 1.1.0.g-1
openssl-1.0 1.0.2.l-1
```

Comment: You could write a PKGBUILD to install an older version of SSL, renamed openssl-ancient, and adapt your program it use it. Otherwise, use a VM, virtualenv, container, etc to run it.

Answer (score 0):

I run a script that goes like this:

```
version=(version to install)

yum install gcc dstat -y

cd /usr/local/src

wget https://www.openssl.org/source/$version.tar.gz

tar -zxf $version.tar.gz

cd $version

./config -Wl,--enable-new-dtags,-zlib,-nossl3,-rpath,'$(LIBRPATH)'

make

make install

mv /usr/bin/openssl /root  #Or substitute where you'd like to back up the old one

ln -sf /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/bin/openssl
#Adjusting this to whatever you get from the output of "which openssl."
```